# Как сделать ссылки в WordPress латинскими буквами без плагинов?

Tags: wordpress, ссылки

Как без плагина сделать транслитерацию ссылок в WordPress?

Comment: Расширите свой вопрос, пока что это какой-то набор слов

Comment: Откройте исходник плагина rustolat и вы увидите, что там 10 строчек. Вам какая разница, будут они в плагине или в functions.php?

Comment: @KAGGDesign только не rustolat и не cyr2lat, а cyr3lat.

Comment: Плагинофобия лечиться изучением матчасти.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, никак. Только написать... свой плагин! Дело в том, что в стандартных WordPress не предусмотрено такой возможности. Можно в этом убедиться, прейдя в Консоль, затем в настройки, а затем - в "Постоянные ссылки". Или же перейдите по ссыке <ваш домен>/wp-admin/options-permalink.php -  все равно ничего не найдете!
А из плагинов лучше всего подходит cyr-to-lat.

Comment: @VladSpirin является ответом.

Comment: @SeVlad, ух, как глаз мозолите ;) И там, и сям =)

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский не понял...

Comment: @SeVlad, натыкаюсь на Вас везде на просторах Интернета =) Начиная от *support.wordpress.org* до *ruSO*.

Comment: Не ругайтесь ребята. Все ок. Жизнь бьёт ключём.